# Google Scripts sending email on Sheet's last cell

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I am trying to create a script that sends me an email of the contents of the last cell in a column.

**GOAL: Last edited cell in a column to be emailed with the cell contents**

For example, I have a sheet that on column C contains values 1,2,3,4, and 5 - with cell C1 containing 1, cell C2 containing 2, etc.

In working with the excel, a new number will be added on the same column, and my goal is to have the latest added cell to be delivered to me in an email - such as whenever C6 is filled and we get the value "6" there, I would recieve an email with the BODY being just "6".

This is what I've been working with but have no had any success in so far.
Thank you for your help!

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
  var startRow = 3; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, numRows, 1);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = "me@gmail.com";
    var message = row[0];
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: i think your are missing `var real_sheet = sheet.getSheets()[0];`

Comment: Try this: `var dataRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3, numRows, 1);` The problem is your `datarange`; the second variable defines the column and you have "1" which means column A, but it should "3" for Column C. Add a logger to confirm the range `Logger.log("range = "+dataRange.getA1Notation());`. FWIW, since your data is a single cell, not sure you need the loop.

Comment: after some testing when the cell is updated but for some reason the email is not sent, the console return an error indicating that I dont have permissions to use MailApp, however when the code is executed from the Apps Script interface it works but automatically no. I am still checking if this is possible will share info later if I found anything that can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

message = row[0] doesn't make any sense.

you've defined row as equal to data[i] so row is not an array and the [] is not applicable.....  try using row instead of message in the email call and eliminating the var message = row[0] stuff